# How to load components before Fragments on saved back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to load activity components that will be shared by fragments. My source works fine when the activity is created for the first time; components are loaded, then fragments are added. However, if the activity is created again, after a state loss, the fragments are created again when calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`. How can I load the components before `super.onCreate` to avoid this failure?

Source code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    //Cannot load components here

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //Here activity restores fragments state, when the activity restores from state loss

    components.load();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, new FragmentLoader()).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Fragments, I would recommend you to create a BaseFragment class and load all your components there. Then extend this BaseFragment class too all the Fragments you are creating and use the components that has been already loaded to display.